# Automatically resolving add/add merge conflicts

Tags: git

We are using

```
git merge --no-ff -Xignore-all-space -Xours masterBranch
```

to automatically refresh an integration branch from some masterBranch in a fully automated build pipeline. This automatically resolves merge conflicts in existing files by taking the hunk from the integration branch (the destination branch).

However, this still leads to merge conflicts in case a file has been newly added on both branches (`CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ...`), and these are not automatically resolved and the merge is stopped, waiting for manual resolution of the conflicts.

- Why does `-Xours` not just take the whole file from "our" branch in that case, as it does with other conflicts?
- Is there a way to configure `git merge` so that in case of **add/add** conflicts, it **does** take the file from "our" branch instead of stopping the merge?

(this is git 2.15.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Add/add" conflicts are part of a group of conflicts that I have not yet found a really good name for, but we might call them *high level conflicts* or *tree conflicts*.  These include *rename/delete* and *rename/rename*, as well.

To get an idea of what this means, remember that `git merge` works by:

- finding a *merge base* (shared on both branches) commit;
- comparing the merge base to each tip: two `git diff`s, as it were.

The output of each of the two `git diff` commands says that some files(s) were changed, and some files were created, deleted, or renamed.

These two diffs have various labels ("ours" and "theirs", "local" and "remote", and so on) but most people can conceptualize them better if they have a person's name attached, so let's say that the base-vs-ours changes are made by Alice, and the base-vs-theirs changes are made by Bob.

Suppose Alice and Bob both started with a file named `READ.ME`.  Alice had to rename it `README.txt` while changing it, and Bob just changed it in place.  To *combine* Alice and Bob's changes, Git will take *both* changes, *and* rename the file from `READ.ME` to `README.txt`.  This is a non-conflicting rename: Git can tell, from each of the two `git diff`s it ran, that Alice renamed the file while changing it, and Bob left the file's name alone while changing it.

The *internal* changes, within this file whose name has changed on Alice's side (but not Bob's), may or may not conflict.  If they *do* conflict, the `-X ours` tells Git whose changes to prefer: Alice's, or Bob's.  These kinds of conflicts are *low level* conflicts: within a single file, as identified after scanning the higher level "tree" changes (files that were created, renamed, or deleted).

Unfortunately, there is no argument to Git to tell it whose changes, if any, to favor in the event of *high level* or tree-wide conflicts.  For instance, if both Alice *and* Bob rename the file, but Alice renamed it `README.txt` and Bob renamed it `README.rst`, Git does not know what to do.  The `-X` argument is given to the *low level* intra-file merge code; it is not used by the high level, files-created-or-renamed-or-deleted merge code.

Hence:

> Why does `-Xours` not just take the whole file from "our" branch in that case, as it does with other conflicts?

That's just not how the `-X` flag is defined.  It applies only to "low level" conflicts.

> Is there a way to configure `git merge` so that in case of **add/add** conflicts, it **does** take the file from "our" branch instead of aborting the merge?

No.  Note, however, that this does not *abort* a merge: it just makes the merge itself stop, with conflicts, to get help from someone or something smarter than Git.  It must be your automation that chooses not to assist Git here, and abort the merge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer and the background information! I have indeed used the term "aborting" wrong in that context - what really happens is that the merge is stopped, leaving the unmerged files in the workspace so that they need to be resolved manually. I have corrected that in my question.