# Automatically resolve conflicts during rebase when files are deleted

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I did a massive search and replace in a large codebase of multiple strings, and created many new commits. Between the time when I started, and when I tried to complete the PR, some of the files had been deleted on the target branch (let's call that target branch `main`). Normally I might do something like this:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/main my-feature-branch
# I now have conflicts on all deleted files
git rm <list-of-deleted-files-here>
git rebase --continue
```

But in this case, I have to repeat that process for many commits, and it's time consuming. As much as I like rebasing my feature branch, I could just throw in the towel and merge instead:

```
git fetch
git switch my-feature-branch
git merge origin/main
# I now have conflicts on all deleted files
git rm <list-of-deleted-files-here>
git merge --continue
```

With the merge I only have to do that extra `git rm` step one time instead of *N* times for each commit if I choose `rebase`. This is an acceptable solution, however, I am stubborn and I really want to avoid adding merge commits to my feature branch, whenever possible. (And I'm convinced it's possible to automate the rebase.) Essentially I am looking for something like `git rebase origin/main -X ours`, except which will also work when one side is deleted. (Note the automatic conflict resolution of `-X ours/theirs` only works when both sides change the file; it doesn't work when one side deletes the file.)

**Side Note:** I feel like an option similar to `-X ours --include-deleted` might be nice.

Comment: [Some related reading here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992714/184546)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, which achieves my goal of *automating* the rebase in  O(1) time. (Meaning a set of operations I need to do just once, instead of repeating over many commits.) Note I'm using `bash` for my commands below.

1. Merge in the target branch. Note I won't keep this merge, but I'm using this to get the list of files that were deleted:

```
git fetch
git switch my-feature-branch
git merge origin/main
```

At this point I have a bunch of files as conflicts.

2. Use `git status` to see the list of files that were deleted. (Or if the only conflicts are deleted files, `git diff` is slightly easier to parse.) Save this list to a file:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U > deleted-files.txt
```

3. Abort the merge. (`git merge --abort`)
4. Check out a new branch from the parent commit of my branch:

```
git switch -c rewrite-deleted-files $(git merge-base @ origin/main)
```

5. Rewrite each of the deleted files with some random text:

```
cat deleted-files.txt | while read file; do echo deleted > $file; done
```

6. Commit the change to those re-written files:

```
git commit -am "wip: rewrite deleted files"
```

Now I have a branch with the same merge-base as my feature branch, with exactly one commit that replaces the entire contents of the deleted files with the word "deleted".

7. Here's the cool part. Now rebase my feature branch onto the deleted files commit, using the `-X ours` strategy to only keep the change from the temporary commit:

```
git rebase origin/main my-feature-branch --onto rewrite-deleted-files -X ours
# It's super satisfying as the rebase goes through every commit without stopping
```

8. Now rebase all of my good commits onto `main` without the temporary commit:

```
git rebase rewrite-deleted-files my-feature-branch --onto origin/main
# Once again, this is super satisfying...
```

9. Delete the temporary file with the list of files in it:

```
rm deleted-files.txt
```

**Note:** I based this answer on [another similar answer I wrote last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72593685/184546), which was for automating rewriting of changes to specific files.

Comment: I never recommend automated resolution of merge conflicts, but at the very least make sure you verify the results very carefully. Git sees a move as deleting the old file and adding the new one. For example, if another dev renamed a class and you modify the original class, after your automatic merge resolution all the code is pointing at the renamed class and your changes is now part of a duplicate, vestigial class that is never instantiated, or worse, different parts of the code instantiate different versions of the class.

Comment: @LightBender That's a valid observation in general. In my case it isn't a big deal because I know exactly what I would do to resolve each commit before I start. What I'm doing here is undoing all changes I made to any files that no longer exist. I agree with you that some inspection should still be done, since if a file was "moved" then I may need to see if the changes I am throwing away need to be re-done in the new file location. (Meaning in my case I could redo the massive find and replace again on all the files that changed between my previous merge-base and now.)

Comment: naturally, it depends on your specific use case as there is no rule in compute science that is absolute. So many people, though, treat git commands on SO like magic spells, I like to litter anything like this with lots of warnings. I have to do git surgery on someone's branch at least once a month because the magic brooms got out of control. :) Nice that your use case won't run up against this problem though.

Comment: @LightBender "the magic brooms got out of control" Haha. Love it!

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar by iteratively doing `grep CONFLICT` in the rebase output, and doing `git rm` on that, using `xargs`. Here is how i did it:

```
git rebase --merge -s recursive -Xtheirs the_other_branch|tee reb1.log
grep CONFLICT reb1.log|cut -f 2 -d ":" | cut -f 2 -d " "|xargs git rm
git rebase --continue|tee reb2.log
grep CONFLICT reb2.log|cut -f 2 -d ":" | cut -f 2 -d " "|xargs git rm
git rebase --continue|tee reb3.log
grep CONFLICT reb3.log|cut -f 2 -d ":" | cut -f 2 -d " "|xargs git rm
git rebase --continue|tee reb4.log
grep CONFLICT reb4.log|cut -f 2 -d ":" | cut -f 2 -d " "|xargs git rm
git rebase --continue|tee reb5.log
```

I had lots of file removals on `the_other_branch`, and changes on them in my current branch. I wanted to delete them anyway, and this worked fine. Maybe you need to modify the way `cut` is used, etc, according to the situation, and maybe you are not interested in looking at the rebN.log files, and then you can have the same name, of course.

This can certainly be done more elegantly and more automatized. To be sure not to destroy things, create extra branches and try there first.

Comment: Note this doesn't answer the question in regards to "automating" the solution without needing to run some command(s) at every commit during the rebase. In fact, my solution does achieve that goal so I'm accepting my answer for now to distinguish it from this one. However, I'm still upvoting your answer because you did add value to my stated mechanism of `git rm <list-of-deleted-files-here>`, by using your `grep` and `cut` commands to automate that portion. Therefore your answer could be "hands off" in theory if you setup the commands beforehand. Thx.